# My page number display has bugs, I know why and where but I don't know how to solve them (PyQt)

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt, tabs

I am making a comic viewer but I am having bugs.

So I have made a program that opens a new tab every time we click onto "File" and then "test".
I created a list that simulates random book lengths.

When we press on the right and left buttons on the first tab, the page we are on is displayed ("page 3 of 23", for example)
However, the problem is that when we open new tabs, there are bugs on the displaying of the page number. The page numbers are over each other in the first tabs, and only the last tab opened seems to be displayed correctly.

I know why. When we open a new tab, we go through the `Open(self)` function to open a tab and `self.pageNumDisp = QLabel("Page : 0 of "+str(len(self.image_list)-1))` prints its' text on the last tab's page number display and THEN adds it to the new tab.

The problem is that I do not know how to solve this bug, and your help would be very welcome.

Actually I had a similar problem with self.prevpagebutton.setEnabled(True/False), and I ended up just not disabling the buttons when the book is at first and last page and instead just starting the book all over, but the actual problem just confirmed me where the issue is.

Here is the part that adds new tabs, creates a list with page numbers and sets the display for page 0 :

```
def Open(self):
    n = str(self.n)
    self.i[n] = 0
    self.tab[n] = QWidget()
    self.tab[n].objectName()
    self.tab[n].layout = QGridLayout()
    self.bookNo = self.bookNo + 1

    self.image_list = []

    for i in range(1,randint(3,50)):
        self.image_list.append(str(i))

    self.whichList[self.bookNo] = self.image_list

    self.pageNumDisp = QLabel("Page : 0 of "+str(len(self.image_list)-1))
    self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp,1, 1)

    self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
    self.nextpagebutton.setObjectName('>{}'.format(self.n))
    self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
    self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
    self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

    self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
    self.prevpagebutton.setObjectName('<{}'.format(self.n))
    self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
    self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
    self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

    self.index[n] = self.tabs.addTab(self.tab[n], "Tab " + str(self.n))
    self.tab[n].setLayout(self.tab[n].layout)
    self.n = int(self.n) + 1
    print(self.i)
```

Here is the part that changes the page number displayed depending on whether we push the right or left button :

```
def readnext(self):
    name = str(self.sender().objectName())
    identifier = name[-1]
    self.i[identifier] += 1
    whichComic = str(self.tabs.currentIndex())

    if self.i[identifier] == -1:
        self.i[identifier] = len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1
    if self.i[identifier] == len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic))):
        self.i[identifier] = 0

    self.pageNumDisp.setText("")
    self.pageNumDisp.setText("Page : "+str(self.i[identifier])+" of "+str(len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1))
    self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp, 1, 1)

    print(self.i)

def readprev(self):
    name = str(self.sender().objectName())
    identifier = name[-1]
    self.i[identifier] -= 1
    whichComic = str(self.tabs.currentIndex())

    if self.i[identifier] == -1:
        self.i[identifier] = len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1
    if self.i[identifier] == len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic))):
        self.i[identifier] = 0

    self.pageNumDisp.setText("")
    self.pageNumDisp.setText("Page : "+str(self.i[identifier])+" of "+str(len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1))
    self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp, 1, 1)

    print(self.i)
```

Here you have my full program, you can try it, it works :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QStatusBar, QToolBar, QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from random import randint


class FenetrePrincipale(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Liseuse de Bandes Dessinées")
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 850
        self.i = 0

        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.move(200, 0)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget()

        self.open = QAction("test", self)
        self.open.triggered.connect(self.table_widget.Open)

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
        self.menuFichier = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.menuFichier.addAction(self.open)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.i = {}
        self.n = 0
        self.index = {}
        self.tab = {}
        self.whichList = {}
        self.bookNo = -1

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def Open(self):
        n = str(self.n)
        self.i[n] = 0
        self.tab[n] = QWidget()
        self.tab[n].objectName()
        self.tab[n].layout = QGridLayout()
        self.bookNo = self.bookNo + 1

        self.image_list = []

        for i in range(1,randint(3,50)):
            self.image_list.append(str(i))

        self.whichList[self.bookNo] = self.image_list

        self.pageNumDisp = QLabel("Page : 0 of "+str(len(self.image_list)-1))
        self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp,1, 1)

        self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
        self.nextpagebutton.setObjectName('>{}'.format(self.n))
        self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
        self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

        self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
        self.prevpagebutton.setObjectName('<{}'.format(self.n))
        self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
        self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

        self.index[n] = self.tabs.addTab(self.tab[n], "Tab " + str(self.n))
        self.tab[n].setLayout(self.tab[n].layout)
        self.n = int(self.n) + 1
        print(self.i)

    def readnext(self):
        name = str(self.sender().objectName())
        identifier = name[-1]
        self.i[identifier] += 1
        whichComic = str(self.tabs.currentIndex())

        if self.i[identifier] == -1:
            self.i[identifier] = len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1
        if self.i[identifier] == len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic))):
            self.i[identifier] = 0

        self.pageNumDisp.setText("")
        self.pageNumDisp.setText("Page : "+str(self.i[identifier])+" of "+str(len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1))
        self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp, 1, 1)

        print(self.i)

    def readprev(self):
        name = str(self.sender().objectName())
        identifier = name[-1]
        self.i[identifier] -= 1
        whichComic = str(self.tabs.currentIndex())

        if self.i[identifier] == -1:
            self.i[identifier] = len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1
        if self.i[identifier] == len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic))):
            self.i[identifier] = 0

        self.pageNumDisp.setText("")
        self.pageNumDisp.setText("Page : "+str(self.i[identifier])+" of "+str(len(self.whichList.get(int(whichComic)))-1))
        self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp, 1, 1)

        print(self.i)


app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = FenetrePrincipale()
window.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStackedLayout, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QStatusBar, QToolBar, QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from random import randint


class FenetrePrincipale(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Liseuse de Bandes Dessinées")
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 850
        self.i = 0

        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.move(200, 0)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget()

        self.open = QAction("test", self)
        self.open.triggered.connect(self.table_widget.Open)

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
        self.menuFichier = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.menuFichier.addAction(self.open)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyBookWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, pages, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)


        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
        self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 720)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
        self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

        self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
        self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 720)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
        self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

        # adding a label for displaying the current page number
        self.pageNumDisp = QLabel()
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.pageNumDisp, 1, 1)

        # Here I use a stacked layout for showing the pages of the book
        # navigating between pages can then be done by changing the index of the layout 
        self.page_viewer = QStackedLayout()
        grid_layout.addLayout(self.page_viewer, 0, 1)

        for n in pages:
            page = QLabel()
            page.setText(str(n))
            self.page_viewer.addWidget(page)

        # connect a slot to the currentChanged signal of the QStackedWidget for updating the label
        self.page_viewer.currentChanged.connect(self.page_changed)
        self.page_changed(0)

    def page_changed(self, page_nr):
        self.pageNumDisp.setText("Page : "+str(page_nr+1)+" of "+str(self.page_count()))

    def page_count(self):
        return self.page_viewer.count()

    def current_page(self):
        return self.page_viewer.currentIndex()

    def readnext(self):
        new_page  = min(self.current_page()+1, self.page_count()-1)
        self.page_viewer.setCurrentIndex(new_page)

    def readprev(self):
        new_page = max(self.current_page() - 1, 0)
        self.page_viewer.setCurrentIndex(new_page)

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def book_count(self):
        return self.tabs.count()

    def Open(self):
        image_list = []
        for i in range(1, randint(3, 50)):
            image_list.append(str(i))
        widget = MyBookWidget(image_list)
        self.tabs.addTab(widget, "Book"+str(self.book_count()))


app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = FenetrePrincipale()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```